# window-configuration-change-hook false positives from desktop-mode

Tags: buffers, hooks, desktop

I'm trying to use `window-configuration-change-hook` in a package to perform some action when a buffer becomes visible for the first time. It works, however when starting Emacs, `desktop-mode` calls `switch-to-buffer` as it is restoring buffers, which triggers `window-configuration-change-hook`. I don't want that to count because the user doesn't actually see the the buffers as they are restored.

Is there a good way to avoid false positives from `desktop-mode`? Or maybe a better way to detect when a buffer becomes visible?

My only current idea is to add a timer or something to ignore cases where the buffer is only "visible" for a very short period, but I don't really like that idea.

Comment: Just a quick-and-dirty thought, without thinking it through: Desktop mode can save variables. You could have it save `window-configuration-change-hook` and restore it. You might have to find out whether vars are restored before or after the buffer switches and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report against `desktop.el`.

Comment: How about locating the `desktop.el` functions responsible for the behavior that you wish to change and let-bind the `window-configuration-change-hook` to `nil` during those functions?

Comment: I'm not sure there isn't some other user of `window-configuration-change-hook` that wants it to run when desktop mode restores buffers. I don't think desktop mode is doing anything "wrong". The way it works was just inconvenient for what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Muir: You needn't clobber the whole hook value; just `remove` *your* function.  You could let-bind that with `around` advice for `desktop-read`.  (Or hopefully you raised a bug report as Stefan suggested, and it's been fixed in the interim...)

Comment: Or instead of messing with the hook, simply let-bind a defvar'd flag which your function looks for, so that it can do nothing when the flag is set.  Or, without writing any advice, test `(boundp 'desktop-buffer-ok-count)` (which is an implementation detail that may or may not remain reliable.  I'm looking at the code in Emacs 29.2.)

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a timer of 0 seconds before checking if the buffer is visible was enough to avoid the false positives:

```lisp
(let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
  (run-with-timer 0 nil (lambda ()
                          (with-current-buffer buffer
                            (when (get-buffer-window nil t)
                              ;; do something now that buffer is visible
                              )))))
```